# How to observe isomorphism between $(R/M)[X]$ and $R[X]/M[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

$R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. It is stated (without proof) in my text that the polynomial ring $(R/M)[X]$ is isomorphic to $R[X]/M[X]$, but I cannot see why this is the case.

I tried to work explicitly from the definitions, looking at cosets of the RHS and comparing them to elements from the LHS, but did not have any luck. I also thought of appealing to the three Isomorphism theorems, but could not see how to apply them to this problem.

Please advise as to how I would go about finding an isomorphism between these two structures, or another method I could use to make better understand this correspondence. Thank you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with maximal ideals. Define a canonical morphism  $R[X]\to (R/I)[X]$ (which extends the canonical projection $R\to R/I$). This sends a polynomial from $R[X]$ in a polynomial whose coefficients are reduced modulo $I$. Then is pretty easy to notice that the kernel is $I[X]$.

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware that it held for ideals in general, so was working on the basis that maximality was important for the desired outcome.